# Bitrise Android build failing without source code changes?

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, google-play-services, bitrise

I just triggered a fresh Bitrise build on an unchanged Android project to find this error now occurring:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:[REDACTED]CompileClasspath'.
> Could not find play-services-identity.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.8.0).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-identity/11.8.0/play-services-identity-11.8.0.aar
> Could not find firebase-iid.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:11.8.0).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-iid/11.8.0/firebase-iid-11.8.0.aar
> Could not find firebase-common.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.8.0).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-common/11.8.0/firebase-common-11.8.0.aar
> Could not find play-services-tasks-license.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks-license:11.8.0).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-tasks-license/11.8.0/play-services-tasks-license-11.8.0.aar
```

I am using React Native, as well as libraries like `tipsi-stripe`, etc. I have no idea where this error came from as it was not associated with any new features/code on my end. How do I fix this?

I do have this line in my `build.gradle`:

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0"
```

I also have this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a [discussion from bitrise site](https://discuss.bitrise.io/t/could-not-resolve-all-files-for-configuration-classpath/5201) where it says that:

> There’s an ongoing `jcenter.bintray.com` issue which affects all
>   Android package downloads from `jcenter.bintray.com`.

There's a simple and reliable solution that can configure a ***Bitrise Build Cache*** in an Android project, so that your dependencies are cached and don’t have to be downloaded from bintray. Here's a guide on [How to cache Gradle dependencies](https://discuss.bitrise.io/t/how-to-cache-gradle-dependencies/194).